Long path aware manifest opt in on older versions of Windows
I have a c++ program for which i created manifest file and set long path aware to true. On newer versions of windows it works as expected. 
But what will happen if i launch my app on older versions of windows, where long path aware is not supported. It will launch and will work as expected like there is no long paths, or it will not launch at all, or will launch and throw  exception when using affected api? 
Is there any problems i should be aware of? 
My program doesnt use constants bigger than 260 for filesystem api and doesnt assume that long path aware should be true. My program just iterates through files using recursive_directory_iterator.
I tried to search through win api documentation, but couldnt found any information about this.

As a general rule, the system ignores unknown manifest entries. The program runs on older versions and behaves as if there were no long path awareness manifest entry.

As @IInspectable said,

As a general rule, the system ignores unknown manifest entries. The
program runs on older versions and behaves as if there were no long
path awareness manifest entry.

It can also be deduced by the document about dpiAwareness.

The minimum version of the operating system that supports the
dpiAwareness element is Windows 10, version 1607. For versions that
support the dpiAwareness element, the dpiAwareness overrides the
dpiAware element. You can include both elements in a manifest if you
want to specify a different behavior for Windows 10, version 1607 than
for an earlier version of the operating system.

